# Counterexample for "the Lie algebra is commutative iff the Lie group is commutative"

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

If $G$ is a connected Lie group, and $\mathfrak g$ is its Lie algebra, then $G$ is commutative iff $\mathfrak g$ is commutative.

But when we remove the "connected" condition, could you provide a counterexample?

Further, without the "connected" condition, is one direction always right?  Thank you!

Comment: Not entirely sure, but in $O_2(\mathbb{R})$, the connected component of the identity is commutative so the Lie algebra is commutative. However, $O_2(\mathbb{R})$ isn’t commutative.

Comment: What about a discrete Lie group?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lie algebra is the tangent space at the identity and since it is defined in terms of smooth paths passing through the identity then it only depends on the identity component.

Therefore any noncommutative Lie group with the commutative identity component will be a counterexample, e.g. $\mathbb{R}\times S_n$, $n\geq 3$, where $S_n$ is the symmetric group of order $n!$ with discrete topology.